# Как записать из одной таблицы в другую определенные поля?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, есть БД, назову её base_one, в ней есть таблица (table_one). Мне надо из `base_one.table_one` взять записи некоторых полей, не всех, а определенных (id,name, gender) и записать в другую базу и другую таблицу (`base_two.table_two`). Буду благодарен, если вы мне подскажите и поможете составить запрос.

Comment: все очень просто =) сам попробуй =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO 'new_table'(`field1`, `field2`, `field3`) SELECT `field4`, `field5`, `field6` FROM `old_TABLE` WHERE ...
```

Comment: если просто добавить,без условий выборки,а тупо перенести то тогда WHERE не нужен?

Comment: Да, не нужен